# Glade radio buttons save state

Tags: application-development, python, glade

I'm writing small application where I have preferences and in preferences I have radio buttons... I managed to get signals out from them but the only problem I got is saving state of them. As this is preferences I need to have these buttons to stay selected when clicked and when program is closed and open again it need to be where it was.

Forgot to mention I'm writing it in python. 
Thanks for any help.

Simon

Answer (score 0):

You can get the radiobutton state by using their `get_active()` method. If you cant to keep their state between application restarts, you'll have to store their values in a configuration file. Have a look at the [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#module-ConfigParser) module for ini-style config storing.